# simple "plugin" system using __call

Tags: php, function, call, magic-methods

so far, I have this:

```
class Foo{

  private $plugin_methods = array();

  public function registerPlugin($caller, $method){
    list($object, $caller) = explode('.', $caller);
    $this->plugin_methods[$object][$caller] = $method;   
  }

  public function _doPluginMethod($object, $name, $args){

    if(isset($this->plugin_methods[$object][$name]))
      return call_user_func_array($this->plugin_methods[$object][$name], $args);

    throw new Exception("Method '{$name}' not defined for '{$object}'.");
  }


  public function __call($name, $args){
    return $this->_doPluginMethod('foo', $name, $args);
  }

}
```

and now I can do this:

```
$foo = new Foo();

$foo->registerPlugin('foo.my_plugin', function($something){
  return $something * 1000;
});

$foo->my_plugin(3453245);
```

But how can I get to the `$this` object inside my "plugin" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the version of PHP you are using. As of PHP 5.4, the use of `$this` in anonymous functions (also called closures) is possible. Prior to that, it wasn't.

Check the changelog here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php